# SetState não funciona dentro de componente

Tags: javascript, react, react-native

Ola, estou tentado dar um setstate porem quando executo ele me retorna que não é uma função

```
renderInput({ input, label, type, meta: { touched, error, warning } }) {
    onChangeTextDestino = async (param) => {
      try {
        this.setState({strEmail: param})
        Alert.alert(this.state.strEmail)
      } catch (e) {
        console.log("error", e)
      }
    }

    return (
      <View>
        <Item error={error && touched} rounded style={styles.inputGrp}>
          <Icon
            active
            name={input.name === "email" ? "mail" : "unlock"}
            style={{ color: "#fff" }}
          />
          <Input
            ref={c => (this.textInput = c)}
            placeholderTextColor="#FFF"
            style={styles.input}
            placeholder={input.name === "email" ? "Email" : "Senha"}
            secureTextEntry={input.name === "password" ? true : false}   
            onChangeText={text => this.onChangeTextDestinos(text)}
            {...input}
          />
          {touched && error
            ? <Icon
              active
              style={styles.formErrorIcon}
              onPress={() => this.textInput._root.clear()}
              name="close"
            />
            : <Text />}
        </Item>
        {touched && error
          ? <Text style={styles.formErrorText1}>
            {error}
          </Text>
          : <Text style={styles.formErrorText2}>error here</Text>}
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Este componente é chamado assim :

```
<Field
   name="email"
   component={this.renderInput}
   type="email"
   validate={[email, required]}
/>
```

Como passo essa função a props da props?

```
component={this.renderInput}
```

Comment: O código é realmente esse? Como vc está exportando os métodos? São arquivos separados? Poderia detalhar um pouquinho mais

Comment: O codigo é realmente este, na classe principal temos o Field, e criamos o componente renderInput para passar como parametro para esse field...

Comment: Jrd, o real problema esta aqui https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52556195/how-send-props-using-field-redux-form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para acertar esse problema foi necessário trocar a forma em que passo para o Fiel o meu componente, ficando assim:

```
const RenderInput = this.renderInput;
<Field component={(props) => <RenderInput {...props} onChangeTextDestinos={onChangeTextDestinos} />} />
```

e passei a receber no meu componente como parâmetro :

```
onChangeTextDestinos
```